# Пройтись по Image в Grid.WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

привет есть код.хочу пройтись по элементам грида  а именно по Image

```
foreach ( var item in mainGrid.Children)
{
    if (item.GetType() == Image) { }
}
```

питаюсь так но что не выходит как правилиьно

```
if (item.Equals(typeof(Image)))
{

}
```

вроде так норм но как теперь у Image убрать картинку которая задана как Source

то есть я думаю убрать источник так

```
oneImage.Source = null;
```

но как это в цикле организовать

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можете использовать класс [VisualTreeHelper](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.media.visualtreehelper(v=vs.110).aspx) для работы с визуальным деревом.

Метод `GetChild` позволяет получить детей указанного элемента, ну а там уже делаете с детьми все, что пожелаете.

xaml:

```
<Grid x:Name="grid1">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Image Grid.Row="0" Source="image/1.png"/>
    <Image Grid.Row="1" Source="image/2.png" />
    <Button Grid.Row="3" Content="Clear Images" Click="Button_Click" />
</Grid>
```

code-behind:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    int childrenCount = VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(grid1);
    for (int i = 0; i < childrenCount; i++)
    {
        var current = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(grid1, i);
        var image = current as Image;
        if (image != null)
        {
            image.Source = null;
        }
    }
}
```

---

Ну или просто:

```
foreach (var gridChild in grid1.Children)
{
    var image = gridChild as Image;
    if (image != null)
    {
        image.Source = null;
    }
}
```

---

#### Update

Чтобы получить прямо все-все `Image`, которые находятся в гриде, независимо от уровня вложенности, можно воспользоваться [этим методом](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/974598/find-all-controls-in-wpf-window-by-type):

```
public static IEnumerable<T> FindVisualChildren<T>(DependencyObject depObj) where T : DependencyObject
{
    if (depObj != null)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(depObj); i++)
        {
            DependencyObject child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(depObj, i);
            if (child != null && child is T)
            {
                yield return (T)child;
            }

            foreach (T childOfChild in FindVisualChildren<T>(child))
            {
                yield return childOfChild;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Код нажатия на кнопку будет выглядеть следующим образом:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    foreach (Image image in FindVisualChildren<Image>(grid1))
    {
        image.Source = null;
    }
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: ясно спасибо    фцвф

Comment: @Санитариум, Пожалуйста!

Comment: слушай а как достать image в это м же гриде но вложеный в Label

Comment: @Санитариум, Дополнил ответ.

Comment: воу. спасибо большое